# Spinner<Integer> bind to IntegerProperty

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to use a FX8 `Spinner` control, but I want to bind the source to an `IntegerProperty`

```
int MIN = 0;
int MAX = 5000;
int STEP = 500;
IntegerProperty integerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(MIN, MAX, STEP);
```

I understand the binding is set via binding to the `valueProperty` in the Value Factory. However this expects `Property<Integer>` and I cannot find a way to cast between `IntegerProperty` and `Property<Integer>`.

Obviously the below generates a compiler error:

```
spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(integerProperty);
```

Do I need to manually assign a change listener for both directions? Surely there is a neater solution using the `valueProperty`, this cannot have been an unforeseen situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap an ObjectProperty:

```
ObjectProperty<Integer> objectProp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(MIN);
IntegerProperty integerProperty = IntegerProperty.integerProperty(objectProp);

Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(MIN, MAX, STEP);

spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(objectProp);
```

[IntegerProperty.integerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.html#integerProperty-javafx.beans.property.Property-) creates a property that's bidirectionally connected to the property it wraps.

Comment: thanks. I decided to go the other way and wrap the Spinner property and call `bindBiDirectional` from the `IntegerProperty` to bind 2 `IntegerProperty` objects (so I don't need to touch the model objects I am working with).

Comment: @SeeMoreGain, please share the code snippet for your approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Like @Buddha I was also interested in some code. However, now i'm using: `spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(integerProperty.asObject());`. Still had to redesign this code, because of a "premature garbage collection" problem, which kept the binding from working. [Following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438466/2642801) fixed it: 1. Declare an instance variable: `private ObjectProperty<Integer> spinnerValue;`. 2. Initialize it: `spinnerValue = integerProperty.asObject();`. 3. Use it: `spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(spinnerValue);`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It would compile but would throw a nullPointerException error at the spinner.getValueFactory...bindBidirectional line. However, when I reversed the binding and did it like this: **objectProp.bindBidirectional(spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty());** it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Buddha and others, we now have one answer in the answer itself and three more answers in the comments. My guess is that one of them is superior/universal and I should only take the time to understand (and use) that one. Can any of you say with confidence which one I should go for? I will give it a day or two and ask this as a new question if I don't hear back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is late but let me propose something else for the others. You can simply call  the **asObject()** on your '*integerProperty*'. That will send you back **ObjectProperty**  value.

```
int MIN = 0;
int MAX = 5000;
int STEP = 500;
IntegerProperty integerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(MIN, MAX, STEP);

spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(integerProperty.asObject());
```